# Hide axis lines and labels in matplotlib except min/max y-label

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have plot in Python matplotlib:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

data = [1, 5, 2, 1, 1, 4, 3, 1, 7, 8, 9, 6, 1]
plt.plot(data)
```

Is there any way to hide axis lines and labels except min and max y-axis label? I know about `plt.axis("off")`, however I would like to show first and last label on y-axis.

The current plot is on the left of the image below and desired plot on the right.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here you format the borders and ticks to hide them and then set the y-ticks explicitly:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

data = [1, 5, 2, 1, 1, 4, 3, 1, 7, 8, 9, 6, 1]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(data)
for side in ['top','right','bottom','left']:
    ax.spines[side].set_visible(False)
ax.tick_params(axis='both',which='both',labelbottom=False,bottom=False,left=False)
ax.set_yticks([min(y),max(y)])
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

There may be a better way, but you can remove it with `plt.axis('off')`. Added in text from.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

data = [1, 5, 2, 1, 1, 4, 3, 1, 7, 8, 9, 6, 1]
plt.plot(data)
plt.axis('off')
plt.text(-0.5,9.0,'9')
plt.text(-0.5,1.0,'1')
```

[image]

Comment: Hardcoded solution. What if `data` will change or size of the plot will be reshaped? :-)

Comment: @ipj you could do something like `plt.text(-0.5,min(data),str(min(data)))`, setting the [transform](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.2/tutorials/advanced/transforms_tutorial.html) if needed.  And You could also make the `-0.5` be more dynamic but that seems to be working fine for a few manipulations.

Comment: Right, parameters can be added and will be fine. I've proposed alternate solution but ticks on y axis for 1 and 9 are present ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
data = [1, 5, 2, 1, 1, 4, 3, 1, 7, 8, 9, 6, 1]
plt.box(False)
plt.yticks(ticks= [min(data),max(data)])
plt.xticks(ticks= [])
plt.plot(data)
```

`plt.box(False)` is used to remove plot frame.

[image]

Please note that ticks for 1 and 9 exists on chart in this approach.